# Any topo options other than msrmaps.com for Google Earth?

Tags: google-earth

Years ago I discovered you could display a topo map in Google Earth from msrmaps.com like this...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <Document>
    <name>ATHENS Topo</name>
    <visibility>0</visibility>
    <GroundOverlay>
        <name>ATHENS Topo</name>
        <visibility>0</visibility>
        <Icon>
            <href>http://msrmaps.com/ogcmap6.ashx?version=1.1.1&amp;request=GetMap&amp;Layers=DRG&amp;Styles=&amp;SRS=EPSG:4326&amp;BBOX=-94.00020,34.25012,-93.87519,34.37511&amp;WIDTH=2000&amp;HEIGHT=2000&amp;format=image/jpeg&amp;transparent=FALSE&amp;Exceptions=se_inimage</href>
        </Icon>
        <LatLonBox>
            <north>34.37511</north>
            <south>34.25012</south>
            <east>-93.87519</east>
            <west>-94.00020000000001</west>
        </LatLonBox>
    </GroundOverlay>
</Document>
```

However, the tiles served by msrmaps.com are very slow to load and may not load at all sometimes.  Does anyone know of another service or method to do this, such as with http://tileserver.mytopo.com/SecureTile/TileHandler.ashx
or
http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/NGS_Topo_US_2D/MapServer

Comment: seen http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/ ?

Comment: But is it possible just to load a portion of that service, rather than the entire set of tiles.  I tried editing the <viewFormat> element but with no luck...<Link>
<href>http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/init?ms=foo&amp;u=Vw2eAsKhyTAcfeZubcZ3rQ==&amp;mv=10</href>
<viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
<viewRefreshTime>0</viewRefreshTime>  
<viewFormat>BBOX=[-94.00020000000001],[34.25012],[-93.87519],[34.37511]</viewFormat>
</Link>

Comment: they are super overlays you need to zoom to the area of interest to view them with kml that is supplied (for authorization of tiles in some datasets)

Answer (score 1):

I finally found another service that will do what I want...
http://www.earthpoint.us/Default.ashx?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <kml xmlns="http://www.opengis.net/kml/2.2" xmlns:gx="http://www.google.com/kml/ext/2.2">
<NetworkLink>
<name>Earth Point Topo Map</name>
<description>Download in progress. Please wait...</description>
<open>0</open>
<refreshVisibility>1</refreshVisibility>
<Style>
<ListStyle>
<listItemType>checkHideChildren</listItemType>
</ListStyle>
<BalloonStyle>
<text>$[description]</text>
</BalloonStyle>
</Style>
<Url>
<href>http://www.earthpoint.us/Default.ashx?RequestID=T8UD1bZJbEOLpt95Fa4fDA</href>
<viewRefreshMode>onStop</viewRefreshMode>
<viewRefreshTime>2</viewRefreshTime>
<viewBoundScale>1</viewBoundScale>
<viewFormat>BBOX=-94.00019733,34.25011759,-93.87519141,34.37511306,[lookatLon],[lookatLat],[lookatRange],[lookatTilt],[lookatHeading],[lookatTerrainAlt],[horizPixels],[vertPixels],[terrainEnabled]</viewFormat>
</Url>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can appreciate that EarthPoint's overlays are free and easy to access, but I found that their low resolution didn't work in my application.  If you are working in only one 7.5' quadrangle, or perhaps only a few, I've found it best to download the PDF's from USGS (it's free) and create my own superoverlays.  (I'm assuming you're in the USA because I think EarthPoint only supports that country's topos.)

If you're in charge of your own superoverlays, the speed of the service will then be up to you, as will the quality of the image.

Answer (score 0):

My preferred Google Earth topographic resource is the [CalTopo USGS layer](http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com/north-american-maps/caltopo-usgs-topo) from http://ge-map-overlays.appspot.com.  Log-in from a Google account is required to download but there is no fee.

This layer is often higher resolution and more readable than the Earth Point resource.

[image: CalTopo USGS]

[image: Earth Point Topo]